# python dbus - receiving event twice

Tags: python, events, dbus

I use a small script using python-dbus and an event from org.kde.amarok /Player:

```
org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.TrackChange
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import dbus
import sys
import time
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

dbus_loop    = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
dbus_session = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
dbus_amarok  = None
dbus_psi     = None

try:
        dbus_amarok  = dbus_session.get_object('org.kde.amarok', '/Player')
        dbus_psi     = dbus_session.get_object('org.psi-im.Psi', '/Main')
except dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
        sys.stderr.write('Psi or Amarok not launched/reachable.\n')
        sys.stderr.flush()
        sys.exit(1)

def hdl_amarok_sig(sender=None):
        try:
                title  = sender.get('title').encode('utf-8')
                album  = sender.get('album').encode('utf-8')
                artist = sender.get('artist').encode('utf-8')
                play_msg = '♪ {} ({}) by {} ♪'.format(title, album, artist)
                print(play_msg)
                dbus_psi.setStatus('online', play_msg)
        except AttributeError:
                pass

dbus_amarok.connect_to_signal('TrackChange', hdl_amarok_sig)

loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Then for example :

```
♪ Með suð í eyrum (Með suð í eyrum við spilum endalaust) by Sigur Rós ♪
♪ Með suð í eyrum (Með suð í eyrum við spilum endalaust) by Sigur Rós ♪
```

That's what is printed and what psi receive of course. And don't find anything about on the web and I've tested it on FreeBSD, Debian unstable and Fedora 18 (KDE4).

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's a bug from Amarok. Using clementine player don't send event twice. Bug reported.